# How to Access the NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: reference, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I'm developing an windows phone app with visual studio 2013 but I have the following issue. I've installed nuget package manager but I don't see the nuget package manager when I right click de References directory.

[image]

[image]

what could be the issue? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To access the NuGet package manager in Visual Studio 2013, go to Tools > Library Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution... (or if you're a CLI type, choose Package Manager Console).